# Eloquent hasMany relationship - can I retrieve an item by a seperate key's value?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have set up a hasMany relationship between a model called Supplier, and a model called SupplierMeta.

SupplierMeta is linked to a table with the structure:

```
id, supplier_id, name, value
```

and the Supplier model has the following relationship defined:

```
public function meta() {
    return $this->hasMany('Model\SupplierMeta');
}
```

The relationship itself works fine, but what I would like to do is define another function that searches within that relationship by the "name" field and returns the value. I would like it to work in this format:

```
$supplier->meta->field_name, or $supplier->meta()->field_name
```

This would either return the "value" field of the relevant SupplierMeta object, if it exists, or otherwise return false. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried?  You should just be able to use `$this->meta()` as a query within a new method..  Keep in mind `meta` is a collection, `meta()` is a query builder object.

Comment: Basically i'd like the relationship to have ->meta treated like an object with keys that are set based on the "name" column from SupplierMeta if that makes sense. So if I run $supplier->meta->field_name it would return a SupplierMeta object with the "name" attribute set to "field_name"'s value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find suppliers by meta name, use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Supplier::whereHas('meta', function ($q) use($metaName) {
    $q->where('name', $metaName);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example macro you can use, which enables you to do `$supplier->meta->meta('field_name');`

```
Collection::macro('meta', function ($name) {
    return $this->first(function ($item) use ($name) {
        return $item->name == $name;
    });
});
```

You could then add a `getMeta()` method to your Supplier model:

```
public function getMeta($name) {
    return $this->meta->meta($name);
}
```

This would let you do `$supplier->getMeta('field_name');`

I'm not totally sure how to get the last part of using it as a property like `$supplier->meta->some_field` however, this is a bit too magical for me.

I think you want to implement some `__get()` method, or a `getMetaAttribute()` on your model. Not totally sure on that part.